# Why does Python not splice out newline character in this seemingly simple code?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, splice

Pretty simple to explain.
We initialize a list:

```
q = [ 'sdf\n', 'sdfd\n' ]
```

Now, we want to remove the newline `\n` from each of the elements that remain, using `readlines()` on the file object.
Using `splice` works fine when I don't put it in a loop:

```
q[0]=q[0][:-1]
```

This gives:

```
q = [ 'sdf' , 'sdfd\n' ]
```

Which is as expected.

But when used in a simple loop,

```
 for i in q:
  if i[-1]=='\n':
     i=i[:-1]
```

This does not change the list at all!
What am I missing?
How do I get rid of all the newline marks?   Python seems to not get rid of them in the loop.

Comment: Any questions or doubts for clarification are welcome, I am very active and online

Answer (score 3):

In python strings are immutable. When you do `i=i[:-1]` you are actually creating a new string with a new value but you are not directly modifying the list which is mutable. If you try to actually modify the list you'll see that it works:

```
>>> for i,j in enumerate(q):
...     if q[i][-1]=='\n':
...         q[i]=q[i][:-1]
...
>>> q
['sdf', 'sdfd']
```

You can also do the same thing using a list-comprehension like so:

```
q[:] = [q[i][:-1] for i,j in enumerate(q) if q[i][-1]=='\n']
```

In the above list-comprehension we use `q[:] = ...` instead of `q = ...` so that we modify `q` entries in place.

Comment: Why not just `[i[:-1] for i in q if i[-1] == '\n']` ?

Comment: Actually, I just realized that that's still wrong, if we want to leave original entries.  We really want `[i[:-1] if i[-1] == '\n' else i for i in q]` to leave the entries where `i[-1] != '\n'` intact.

Comment: @IanMcLaird: Typically, you don't index or slice, you just `rstrip`: `[x.rstrip('\n') for x in q]` If it doesn't end in a new line, it's unmodified, if it does, it's stripped.